# Find matching strings in text even string seperated by one word using vba office word

Tags: string, vba, search, ms-word, find

I need your help on this problem. I'm trying to write a VBA Macro in Office Word that will search for defined strings in the document text. That was straightforward for me to achieve.
**The particularity now is** If in the text some strings are separated by a word, then make a match.

Here is the basic code to find matching strings in the doc but I'm struggling to figure out how to make a match on one word separated strings.

```
Sub HighlightMatches()
    Dim range As range
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wordsArray

wordsArray = Array("Lion", "Hello", "Cat", "Lorem Ipsum")
For i = 0 To UBound(wordsArray)
    Set range = ActiveDocument.range

    With range.Find
    .Text = wordsArray(i)
    .Format = True
    .MatchCase = False
        Do While .Execute(Forward:=True) = True
            range.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
        Loop
    End With

Next
End Sub
```

**What I'm trying to achieve:** If in the document text there is a sentence like "Lorem is Ipsum and that's all"; I would like the search to highlight "Lorem is Ipsum" even if "lorem is Ipsum" is not in the wordsArray.

I will be thankfull if you guys can help me with this. Thanks in advance for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The strings, separated by word are easy to be found - try to split the string and then count the units in the array. In general, assuming that you can achieve that easily and summarizing your problem to **find a match when I have two words with a random word in between** this would pretty much do what you need:

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strText         As String
    Dim arrMatches      As Variant

    Dim arrIn        As Variant
    Dim myArr1          As Variant
    Dim myArr2          As Variant
    Dim lngC            As Long

    arrMatches = Array(Array("lorem", "ipsum"), Array("of", "the"))

    strText = "lorem my ipsum is simply dummy text of fu the printing " & _
                    "and typesetting industry."

    arrIn = Split(strText)

    'we need to check always 2 less:
    For lngC = LBound(arrIn) To UBound(arrIn) - 2
        For Each myArr1 In arrMatches
            If myArr1(0) = arrIn(lngC) And myArr1(1) = arrIn(lngC + 2) Then
                Debug.Print arrIn(lngC) & " " & arrIn(lngC + 1) & " " & arrIn(lngC + 2)
            End If
        Next myArr1
    Next lngC

End Sub
```

It is probably difficult to understand what it does, thus change the `arrMatches` a few times and the `strText` as well. Then debug with `F8`. In this case it returns in the immediate window the following:

```
lorem my ipsum
of fu the
```

This is because we have 2 arrMatches `Array(Array("lorem", "ipsum"), Array("of", "the"))` and the only strings in the text, where these matches are present with a word between them are the one above.

Edit: If you want to make it working for more than 1 word in between, check it like this:

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub TestMe()

    Dim strText         As String
    Dim strPrint        As String
    Dim arrMatches      As Variant
    Dim arrInput        As Variant
    Dim myArr1          As Variant
    Dim myArr2          As Variant
    Dim lngC            As Long
    Dim lngC2           As Long
    Dim lngC3           As Long

    arrMatches = Array(Array("lorem", "ipsum"), Array("of", "the"))
    strText = "lorem my ipsum is simply dummy text of fu the printing " & _
               "ipsum and typesetting industry."

    arrInput = Split(strText)
    For lngC = LBound(arrInput) To UBound(arrInput)
        For Each myArr1 In arrMatches
            For lngC2 = lngC To UBound(arrInput)
                If myArr1(0) = arrInput(lngC) And myArr1(1) = arrInput(lngC2) Then
                    strPrint = ""
                    For lngC3 = lngC To lngC2
                        strPrint = strPrint & " " & arrInput(lngC3)
                    Next lngC3
                    Debug.Print strPrint
                End If
            Next lngC2
        Next myArr1
    Next lngC
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you @Vityata This works great. Now what I have to do is to try insert it the right way in my code. Thank you again for your time. I was asking myself how the code would turn out if we could just find and highlight the words in the sentence even if there are separated by multiple words!? Do you think you can help with that?

Comment: Works great @Vityata You're awesome! Thank you for your time and your responsiveness :D. I will go on that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution to the problem as I stated it. It is more specific and more scalable than the solution provided by **@Vityata** but which was helpfull as I get a bit of the logic from it.

```
Sub HighlightMatches()
    Dim phraseRange As Object
    Dim phraseIndex As Long
    Dim i As Long
    Dim wordsArray() As Variant
    Dim splitedList As Variant
    Dim keywords As String
wordsArray = Array("Faux Texte", "Lorem Ipsum")
For i = 0 To UBound(wordsArray)
    Set phaseRange = ActiveDocument.Sentences
    splitedList = Split(Trim(wordsArray(i)))
    If UBound(splitedList) > 0 Then
        For phraseIndex = 1 To ActiveDocument.Sentences.Count
            keywords = ""
            Set phraseRange = ActiveDocument.Sentences(phraseIndex)
            With phraseRange.Find
                For t = 0 To UBound(splitedList)
                    keywords = keywords + "(" & splitedList(t) & ")(*)"
                Next
                'MsgBox keywords
                .Text = keywords
                .Format = True
                .MatchWildcards = True
                    If .Execute(Forward:=True) = True Then
                        'MsgBox "It Works"
                        phraseRange.HighlightColorIndex = wdYellow
                    End If
            End With
        Next
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

That's all. I hope this will save time to others.

Comment: Can i use the same code to read text with means Test-1 but mentioned in different format like TEST-1, TEST:1, Test_1: Test1: like this